# Why wont my Excel files download in href tag?

Tags: excel, tags, href

Here are some of the  href tags.

```
<td style="font-weight: bold;" class="auto-style10" headers="Sample Forms">
 &nbsp;Sample Forms&nbsp;<br /><a 
href="../../Skin/faq_help/help%20Library/PSM%20templates/Oilandnh3Log.xlxs" 
target="_blank">Ammonia Loss and Oil Log</a> <br />
<a href="../../Skin/faq_help/help%20Library/PSM%20templates/Leak 
Calculator.xls" target="_blank">Ammonia Loss Calculator<br />
<a href="../../Skin/faq_help/help%20Library/PSM%20templates/CONTRACTORS On-
Site Safety Review Form.docx" target="_blank">Contractor On-Site Safety 
Review<br />
```

All the docx files work fine but not the Excel files. I tried changing them to .xls ( older version ) but I still get this error :

404 - File or directory not found.
The resource you are looking for might have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

I know the file is there and path is correct